# What is this black flashing thing and how to delete it?

Tags: smoke-simulation

So earlier on, I applied a smoke effect to the liquid on the coffee I made. I wanted to delete it, and I reversed it. I don't think I did it properly. Now when I move it in Material Preview, I see these black, jagged black spots on the cup whenever I move it. I don't know where it is coming from. I think it is the smoke, but I don't see the option to turn it off. Or to delete it. You can only see it when you move around, and IDK how to take videos on computer.

Here is the file: [Click](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcgd8cv44ths6af/Dn.blend?dl=0)

Note that the uploading thing is slow for me, so posting a link now for now, until it works faster for me.

I hope someone knows how to fix it.
Also the problem is from the liquid. Not from the smoke domain and steam at the last. I am trying to figure out how to make steam using that, but need to get rid of the black spots (which was another steam thing again).

Thank you!

Comment: I can't look at the blend file currently but have you deleted the smoke domain?

Comment: @Phönix64 I feel it's a bug with volume absorption...since another user who has more experience it said that...but IDK where the first smoke domain is. The second is fine.

Comment: You can put videos using XShare, its free. And then maybe take a screenshot of the video when the problem starts occuring.